# Systemd reload process gets killed

Tags: linux, bash, service, centos, systemd

My systemd unit file looks something like this

```
start() {
   java -jar server.jar &
}
reload() {
   #do some application specific reload stuff
   start
}
```

I'm realizing that right when the systemd call to reload finishes, the process running `java -jar` is actually dead. Systemd seems to think that my reload process is done and kills it. Is there any way to configure and cancel this process killing behavior? I have tried disowning the process, and messing with `KillMode=blah` and `Type=blah` in the service file, but no result.

Running on CentOS 7.4

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question, do you want the systemd unit file for executing server.jar, right?
Try it by following sequences.

First create your blah service unit file.

```
# vim /etc/systemd/system/blah.service

[Unit]
Description=blah service
After=network.target
Requires=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/blah
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar server.jar
Restart=always
User=blah_USERNAME

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And reload the blah service unit file.

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
```

Test it!

```
# systemctl start blah
# systemctl status blah
# systemctl restart blah
# systemctl status blah
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: So I already have the systemd unit file. But when I call reload(), the process only lives for as long as reload is executing. For example, if I put `sleep 10` in the reload function, then there will be two instances of the server running for ten seconds. Then, the reload function is done and the jar is killed...which is not what I want